# Oracle DB Ora-01839: date not valid for month specified. 29-02-2016 leap year

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, leap-year

We all know today is a special day. Its the `29th of February 2016` of a **leap year**.

We receive an error message from some tables in our Oracle DB. The error is:`Oracle ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified`.

For example a simple select where the error occurs:`select * from table where table_date > sysdate -0.1;`

For other tables this select makes no problem, just for some of the tables.

Is there a way to fix this issue? Because we are not able to use many tables today.

We are using `Oracle 12c`.

Comment: What is the datatype of column `table_date`?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit its a `date`

Comment: Does `select table_date from...` also get that error - maybe it's a different column that is failing on implicit conversion? Is it a table or a view (which calculates something); or does it have a virtual column? What is the NLS_DATE_FORMAT in the session that gets the error? Are you seeing this in a particular client, and can you reproduce in SQL\*Plus?

Comment: Well, you wasted the answer I'd mostly written up to explain interval handling, but glad you figured it out *8-) It is [documented behaviour](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00208).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After intensive research, its clear why some of our selects does not work today. The error is caused by the keyword `interval` and its a known issue. (Or it's how the [ANSI/ISO spec](http://www.inf.fu-berlin.de/lehre/SS05/19517-V/FolienEtc/sql-foundation-aug94.pdf) says it should work, bottom of page 205/top of page 206)

Here is a qoute from the [oracle community blog](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2355574?start=0&tstart=0):

**Question**:

```
select to_date('2012-feb-29','yyyy-mon-dd') + interval '1' year as dt from dual;

ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified
01839. 00000 -  "date not valid for month specified"
*Cause:    
*Action:

select to_date('2012-feb-29','yyyy-mon-dd') + interval '2' year as dt from dual;

ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified
01839. 00000 -  "date not valid for month specified"
*Cause:    
*Action:

select to_date('2012-feb-29','yyyy-mon-dd') + interval '3' year as dt from dual;

ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified
01839. 00000 -  "date not valid for month specified"
*Cause:    
*Action:

select to_date('2012-feb-29','yyyy-mon-dd') + interval '4' year as dt from dual;

29-FEB-16 00:00:00


select to_date('2012-feb-29','yyyy-mon-dd') + interval '1' day as dt from dual;

01-MAR-12 00:00:00

select to_date('2012-feb-29','yyyy-mon-dd') + interval '1' month as dt from dual;

29-MAR-12 00:00:00
```

**Answer**:

> That's just how INTERVALs work. Leap years are the least of the
>   problem; adding 1 month to March 31 results in the same error. If you
>   want to make sure that the result is a valid DATE, then use
>   ADD_MONTHS. (There's no separate function for adding years; use
>   ADD_MONTH (SYSDATE, 12*n) to get the DATE that is n years from now.)

---

**Why it happens in our case:**

In our case, we used virtual private database for some of our tables because of security reasons. And there we applied the `interval` keyword in most of the selects.

**What to do instead:**

Use `ADD_MONTHS` instead.

```
select add_months(to_date('2012-feb-29','yyyy-mon-dd'), 12) as dt from dual;
```

Comment: Just a note, for Daylight-Saving-Time the behavior is also different. Compare `TIMESTAMP '2015-10-25 01:30:00 Europe/Berlin' + INTERVAL '1' MONTH` vs. `ADD_MONTHS(TIMESTAMP '2015-10-25 01:30:00 Europe/Berlin', 1)`

Comment: We mistakenly had code similar to the following (which caused this Oracle exception today due to ODP.NET using INTERVAL with `DbFunctions.AddYears`):
`DataSet.Where(e => e.Date >= DbFunctions.AddYears(DateTime.Now, -1))`

Comment: Thank you for this. I wonder what is the point of even supporting date+interval if you're not going to support crossing month boundaries and leap years...