# Adding date intervals can’t handle going past the end

Tags: oracle, date

I’m not very familiar with Oracle, so all of this is a bit new to me.

If I have a simple calculation such as below:

```sql
WITH dates AS (SELECT date '2020-01-31' AS jan31, date '2020-02-29' AS feb29 FROM dual)
SELECT
    jan31 + interval '1' month AS nextmonth,    --  29 Feb 2020
    feb29 + interval '1' year AS nextyear       --  28 Feb 2021
FROM dates;
```

both calculations would fail because the result is out of range.

I have tried the same in PostgreSQL, MariaDB and Microsoft SQL Server, using their own corresponding expressions, and they all result in the commented dates; that is, they clip the result to the end of the month rather than overflow.

I am familiar with the `add_months` function, which does make the appropriate adjustment, but I wonder whether there is a way of getting the expression `date + interval` to work reliably.

Comment: There isn't. This is why you will find that, in the Oracle world, `add_months` is used almost exclusively for such computations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered here:

[Oracle DB Ora-01839: date not valid for month specified. 29-02-2016 leap year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35695175/oracle-db-ora-01839-date-not-valid-for-month-specified-29-02-2016-leap-year)

Basically, that is just the way Oracle implemented it

Comment: So, the short answer is that you can add `date + interval` except that it doesn’t work. Seriously, Oracle may have some merits, but I haven’t seen anything in the SQL to convince me.